# Blockquotes (or divs) in two columns

Tags: html, css

I have html generated from markdown, so structure changes are limited.

I have an html that looks more or less like this:

```
<div id="about">
<h1>About</h1>
<blockquote>1</blockquote>
<blockquote>2</blockquote>
<blockquote>3</blockquote>
<blockquote>4</blockquote>
<p>some text</p>
<blockquote>5</blockquote>
<blockquote>6</blockquote>
<blockquote>7</blockquote>
</div>
```

I would like only blockquotes to appear in two columns. I was thinking about stilling it somehow that every odd blockquote gets "float: left" but I don't see how this can be done with this structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the structure, make those blockquotes stack horizontally and make sure that any two of them have a common width of 67% to 100%. For example:

```css
blockquote {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  width: calc(50% - 1em); /* to compensate the space between two blocks */

  /* just to higlight the structure */  
  background: #ff000010; 
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <h1>About</h1>
  <blockquote>1</blockquote>
  <blockquote>2</blockquote>
  <blockquote>3</blockquote>
  <blockquote>4</blockquote>
  <p>some text</p>
  <blockquote>5</blockquote>
  <blockquote>6</blockquote>
  <blockquote>7</blockquote>
</div>
```

Note that this is not technically a column layout, so it will look strange if the blockquotes contain content that is significantly different in height.

Comment: Indeed content differs in height. Also would love to see single (or the one missing pair) blockquote to stretch to whole document. wkhtmltopdf fails to render it properly as well. Still I'm impressed this works. +1 Thanks.

Comment: p.s. It's not that I don't want to change the structure. It's more about it being generated from markdown document, so it's much more difficult to properly structure it.

Answer (score 1):

The Flexbox way, with an orphan blockquote stretched to the parent's full width (`flex-grow: 0;` to turn it off). Has it's own cons and slightly more code.

```css
#about { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#about > * {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#about > blockquote {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* just to higlight the structure */ 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #00f1;
  background: #f001;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <h1>About</h1>
  <blockquote>1</blockquote>
  <blockquote>2</blockquote>
  <blockquote>3</blockquote>
  <p>some text</p>
  <blockquote>4</blockquote>
  <blockquote>5</blockquote>
  <blockquote>6</blockquote>
  <blockquote>7</blockquote>
</div>
```